# Is an organism possible which has an organ at a pressure of 5.5 bar/80psi?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, xenobiology

In an earth-like environment (above sea level), could an animal have an organ which could exert pressures equal to 5.5 bar 80 psi, enough to maintain liquid CO<sub>2</sub>? Taking in account that the temperature is max 0 Celsius. In addition, the organ would preferably have around 36 liters of liquid CO<sub>2</sub>. Any excess heat is dispersed throughout the body and evaporated if needed.

Comment: There's something of a disconnect between your title and your text.  At earth-normal temperatures, the critical point of CO2 is _74_ atm of pressure, so you're not going to get any liquid CO2 at 5.5.

Comment: @AlexP with machines that create more than 80 bars.

Comment: Doesn't making liquid CO2 require the good pressure _and_ the good temperature? So you can't sum up the conditions it to be X or Y pressure? And without talking about the constraints, what would be the use for primitive creatures to develop this feature in the first place :/?

Comment: Wait, how can you have a 5.5 bar pressure above water-level in an earth-like environment...?

Comment: The edit doesn't correct the fundamental error in the question's assumptions, it remains unclear as a result because of the inherent contradictions.

Comment: @Tortliena the organ produces that pressure, and the creature lives on land, if you look at some of the answers, they use the "aid" of underwater pressure to reach the specified 5.5 bar

Comment: @ARogueAnt. what remains unclear? please say

Comment: 5.5 bar at Earth-like temperatures won't give you liquid carbon dioxide, you need closer to 80 bar. You need to make your mind up, do you want liquid carbon dioxide or a pressure of 5.5 bar at Earth-like temperatures, because both is impossible in this universe.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. you mean 80 psi, not bar, right? and and also re-read the question, 0 Celsius is the maximum temperature there, thank you, anything else? please do tell

Comment: No I mean 80 ish bar, as thoroughly explained in Trish's answer, 72 bar ish at 0C.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. You need around 80 psi or 5.2 bar to get liquid carbon dioxide at temperatures of 31 Celsius, 80 bar is 1160 psi

Comment: @Dexyan your data is **wrong**. Just look into a phase diagram. 5.2 bar is for -56.6 °C!

Comment: Perhaps if you point us to where you're getting your figures, this can be sorted out.

Answer (score 6):

**You can easily get 5 atmospheres of pressure in an earthlike environment.**

[image: diver]

https://www.girlsthatscuba.com/advanced-open-water-course/

She is producing 5 atmospheres of pressure between her hands.   And she is strong but not super strong.  It is very earthlike there because she is off the coast of Indonesia.

Actually there are 5 atmospheres of pressure all around her because that is the pressure at 60 meters underwater.  You can get even more pressure if you go deeper and there is a lot of deeper below 60 meters.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @SRM: The question asks: *"could an animal have an organ which could exert pressures equal to 5.5 earth atmospheres of pressure"*. The picture shows an animal whose lungs exert a pressure of 5.5 atmospheres. True, they are helped by the environment, but the question does not forbid it.

Comment: Does it allow the creature to make liquid CO2, which is the question title? No.

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

Physics says: it's possible if you are a machine that can withstand extreme temperatures or pressures. Biology just says **nope** not within a window that can support any life.

### How it came to that...

$$PV=nRT$$
That's the gas law. You want to get CO<sub>2</sub> to go liquid. You assert that's at 5.5 atmospheres<sup>1</sup>. Or 557288 Pa. Let's assume that we want to compress 1 mol.

$$\frac {\text T}{\text V}=\frac{557288 \text { Pa}}{1 \text { mol}\times 8.31446261815324 \frac {\text{J}} {\text{K mol}}}\\=\frac{557288 \frac{\text{J}}{\text m^3}}{8.31446261815324 \frac {\text{J}} {\text{K}}}\\=67026.34019\frac{\text K}{\text m^3}$$

Now, under standard pressure and temperature ( $10^5\text{ Pa}, 273.15\ \text K)$, , 1 mol of gas takes 22.4 liters, or 0.0224 m³. We want to compress, as that's what OP said. So, we have an area of about 1 meter by 1 meter by 224 millimeters. It takes in one mol of air. Let's see what happens in case we pin the temperature to 273.15 K - an isothermic attempt.

$$\frac 1 {\text{V}}=\frac {67026.34019}{273.15}\frac{\text K}{\text {K m}^3} \\ V=\frac 1 {245.3829} \text m^3 = 0.004075\ \text m^3 $$
A muscle set that compresses our room from 22.4 mm to 4 mm height <sup>2</sup>? No way, that can't work. We can't pin the temperature. Let's assume the best we can manage is *halve* the volume of the gland, that is [technically 10 % more than typical muscles can manage](http://muscle.ucsd.edu/musintro/contractions.shtml), but halving is easier for math. Well, what happens to the temperature?

$$\frac {\text T_1}{\text V_1}=\frac {\text T_2}{\text V_2}\\{\text V_1}=2\times{\text V_2}\\\frac {\text T_1}{\text V_1}=\frac {\text T_2}{2\times \text V_1}\\2\times {\text T_1}= {\text T_2}\\T_2=546.3\text { K}
$$
Eh... Nope! that's not an option, our creature just turned itself into well cooked, no, charred meat by trying to make CO<sup>2</sup>. In fact, it could set [heavily processed leather on fire!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature)

---

### Corrections

1. CO<sub>2</sub> only turns liquid at [74 bar at 31 °C.](https://www.ascoco2.com/en/co2-production-and-co2-recovery-plants/general-information-about-co2) The cited number for CO<sub>2</sub> comes from the triple point of [5.1 atm at -56.6 °C](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Electuredemonstrations/Composer/Pages/48.36.html), which translates into 74 PSI at -70 °F. [Nearly no bacteria](https://phys.org/news/2013-08-lowest-temperature-life.html) can survive at that low temperature for extended periods - one of those rare few is [Panagrolaimus davidi](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0104526). The temperature is an **essential** information for the gas law.
2. T/V is 8900154.27 K/m³ for the corrected pressure. Chucking in the temperature of 304.14 K gets us a required reduction of our initial 224 mm tall chamber to 0.034 mm or 34 µm. About **half a human hair**.

---

### Conclusion

The gas law is like the moon, and the moon is a harsh mistress. Either you demand the clearly impossible from muscles, or you cook your creature alive. And there is no sweet spot available where the temperature increase for the required pressure and the available compression both are inside the range of supporting carbon-based life.

The closest equivalent organ that can create pressures by self-compression is the heart. It manages 120 mmHg - or 15998.7 Pa - or almost 1.6 bar. That's too low by a factor of 47 to make liquid CO<sub>2</sub>.

### Update

**The gas law doesn't like your idea.** You say 0 °C or 0 °F, and 5.5 bar, but you totally misunderstand the fundamentals of [what Wikipedia tells you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_carbon_dioxide). That is not liquid CO<sub>2</sub>, as a simple gaze into a **phase diagram of CO<sub>2</sub> will easily show. To have liquid CO<sub>2</sub> at or above 255.37 K or 273.15 K demands pressures much higher. Note that the left bar is a **logarithmic** scale, not linear! In fact, the mere gaze into that diagram will tell you, that at 273.15 K, CO<sub>2</sub> starts to go liquid at about 60-80 bar (math says: 72 bar) and stay so till above 5000 bar. For 255.37 K, we are at about 20-30 bar minimum. In fact, CO<sub>2</sub> **can't** be liquid above the critical point of 31.1 °C - 304.25 K.

[image]

To have liquid CO<sub>2</sub>, you pick any temperature in Kelvin between the white triple point and black critical point, and then see where the line between blue and gray is there. **That** is your required pressure, which you can calculate with the gas law above. **None** of the solutions you will get is feasible for an organic being.

Comment: What about an animal with specific biological features to make itself more difficult to burn alive?

Comment: @EkadhSingh we are talking about 273.15 °C or 523.67 °F. That is enough to [*set processed leather on fire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature)

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a shot

Comment: You should have just said nRT is constant, so PV is too, so to get 5.5x increase in pressure you need 5.5x decrease in volume. That would have let you realize that you made a significant mistake - it's not 224 to 4, it's 22.4 to 4. Also, you're assuming that it has to be done in a single chamber. Why wouldn't there be multiple chambers that incrementally increase the pressure?

Comment: Transfer of the volume from chamber to chamber wouldn't work. But the missing decimal I must have read over. Doesn't help with the needed 74 bar @31°C though, where we really need to go to the horrible horrible half-hair thickness.

Comment: you mean 5.2 bar, 74 psi? right?

Comment: and it could have protective structures around the organ, refrigeration and high insulators, like something of mineral wool to insulate, at heat exits so it gets even less hot, without any real exits of pressure

Comment: @Dexyan Just plain **no**. [For carbon dioxide, the triple point is -56.6 °C and 5.1 atm. Below this point, either raising the temperature or lowering the pressure causes the solid form to sublime, or go directly into the vapor phase. To observe this with water, we must reduce the pressure to below 4.585 torr. Carbon dioxide at 1 atm is well below the triple point pressure, and a block of frozen dry ice sublimes at -78.5 °C, which is why it is known as “dry ice.”](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~lecturedemonstrations/Composer/Pages/48.36.html) That 74 psi is for **-70 °F**, no life is possible

Comment: @Dexyan in other words: the 74 psi is **meaningless** without the temperature, and no pressure-temperature combination that creates liquid CO2 is in any way survivable.

Comment: @Dexyan just look at the updated answer with the phase diagram and you will see that what you want is impossible.

Comment: This assumes that the CO2 is compressed in a single event.  It may be possible to compress the CO2 in multiple small amounts, during which the creature can deal with the excess heat of the process, before adding the liquid CO2 to its stored supply.  Think that there may be a seperate compressor and storage tank.

Comment: @MontyWild Multiple stages might alleviate the *thermal* problem, but not the *pressure* problem. There is no biological construction that can withstand the required pressures trying to blast it into bits. We are talking about 80 times atmospheric pressure. roundabout 1200 pound pressing on every square inch of storage container. Human Lungs can only contain about 25 PSI before they blow their gasket... Also, the higher the pressure in the storage, the more "dead lift" you have in the compressor stage, which just is needed to equalize the pressure of the new gas to the pressure in the storage.

Answer (score 1):

5.5 atmospheres is about 80 psi. The bite force of dogs can be measured in the 700 psi range, big cats in the 1000 psi range and bears in the 1200 psi range. It seems reasonable to me that an animal could evolve to produce this kind of pressure in other situations.

This is a list of top biters by body weight as a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bite_force_quotient

Comment: that on a body that can change its shape and that is not fully internal. the only muscle that would be relevant is a heart.

Comment: "could an animal have an organ which could exert pressures equal to 5.5 earth atmospheres of pressure?" @Trish, the clear answer is yes despite your wish to complicate things with additional criteria. Note, the mouth IS an organ and thus many real animals, humans included are able to exert pressures in excess of 5.5 atmospheres.

Comment: The **lungs** can create some 70 PSI, not the mouth. where are the Ok, Lungs and heart are relevant, but the lungs use levers and several dozen muscles working together and only can compress their air-sack by some small percentage.  but to liquefy CO2 (which seems to be what OP wants from the title) at room temperature you need 74 bar, which is something like 1073 psi.

Comment: Bite forces are that high because they are measured on the *needle sharp teeth* which means a normal force divided by a tiny area gets a high pressure.

Comment: This says nothing about liquid CO2.

Comment: @Trish: So what? The question asks for 5.5 atm, it does not say anything about compression, volume or area.

Comment: Title of question: organism which makes liquid CO2, is it possible? - basic knowledge of the gas law would tell you you need to compress gas from all sides - or rather *withstand* the equal pressure you exert onto the gas on all sides. Otherwise, you get a kettle explosion.

Comment: The question got updated. please update accordingly.